# Iterating over properties of an object in Script#

Tags: c#, javascript, iteration, script#

What Script# code would generate the following JavaScript?

```
var obj = eval('(' + jsonText + ')');

for (key in obj)  // what C# code translates to this iteration?
{
    // ...
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can come close with:**

```
Object obj = Script.Eval("(" + json + ")");
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in Dictionary.GetDictionary(obj))
{

}
```

**which generates (in Script# 0.7.2):**

```
var obj = eval('(' + json + ')');
var $dict1 = obj;
for (var $key2 in $dict1) {
    var entry = { key: $key2, value: $dict1[$key2] };
}
```

---

*Side Note*: There is a binding in Script# already for native JSON. You could replace `Script.Eval(...)` with `Json.Parse(...)` in namespace `System.Serialization` if you are targeting browsers with native JSON support or will be including the popular [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library or the like.